# nodes missing from node editor

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor

The default defuse node missing from node editor - i have tried repairing / did a reinstall -- changed the cycles render // chose use node editor from the material tab. Blender 2.78c. I cannot insert or create a new node.

here is the screen shoot.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

ahh... my bad.. the use node check box was not ticked.

Comment: Diffuse shader node (if you were looking for it in the question) is material node whereas your nodetree is displaying Compositing nodes. So which nodes did you want to use?